# How to remove directory from terminal title and only keep running command?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Is it possible to only show the running command in `gnome-terminal`'s title? I couldn't find any appropriate option in the preferences menu.

[image: gnome-terminal]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7110386/3140225) in this similar question in Stack Overflow [Bash - Update terminal title by running a second command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076127/bash-update-terminal-title-by-running-a-second-command), you can add the following at the end of your `.bashrc`:

```bsh
trap 'echo -ne "\033]2;$(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g")\007"' DEBUG
```

Then run:

```bsh
source ~/.bashrc
```

for the change to take effect.

The above command changes your terminal's title to your currently running command. If a command is not currently running, your terminal's title is the default one.

You may also be interested in having the last run command inside brackets as your title. According to this answer [How to set the terminal title to show the current running command while it's running and to show it in brackets once it's finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16975889/3140225), you have to also add this in your `.bashrc`:

```bsh
export PS1="\033]2;[\$(history 1 | sed 's/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g')]\007$PS1"
```